# Force uninstall app (by deleting app's files from SD card)

Tags: apps, store, sd-card

I had a faulty install of an app from Store and now I have this app in my menu, where if I launch it, nothing happens and also when I try to uninstall it, nothing happens.

Now, I got the idea that (since all my apps are installed on SD cards) I can take SD card out and plug it to computer and then I can delete app's files manually to remove trace of it from phone.

But, when i opened **WPSystem > Apps** there are just a bunch of directories named by GUID (i.e. `{8D93224F-2808-E011-9264-00237DE2DB9E}`) and I can't find the app I want to delete.

Does anyone have any idea how can I identify the correct app by GUID or by any other means, so that I can delete it's files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

1. Go to *Settings->System->Storage->SD card*
2. Move all your apps to phone memory except the one you want to uninstall.
3. Now it should be easy to delete the app.